# Proving all states of a recurrent Markov chain are null recurrent

Tags: probability

There is a chain with states $0$, $1$, $2$, ...

The probability of going from state $0$ to $1$ is $1$.

The probability of going from state $i$ to $i+1$ is $p_{i}$

The probability of going from state $i$ to $0$ is $1$ $-$ $p_i$

If I know the chain is recurrent, how do I prove that all states are null recurrent if and only if the sum $1$ $+$ $p_1$ + $p_1p_2$ + $p_1p_2p_3$ + ... goes to infinity?

Comment: Let $p_0=1$. Then $P(T> t)=\prod_{i=0}^{t}p_i$ and $E(T)=\sum_{t\ge 0} P(T>t)$

Comment: @A.S. You condensed my answer into one line, impressive :)

Comment: What does T represent?

Comment: Return time to $0$ when starting at $0$. @Math I wasn't even consciously aware of the alternative characterization of null-recurrence that you used.

Comment: Right, thank you, I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

If $\nu$ is an invariant measure for $P$, that is, $\nu=\nu P$, then \begin{align}\nu(0)&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (1-p_i)\nu(i),\\
\nu(1) &= \nu(0),\\
\nu(i) &= p_i\nu(i-1),\ i\geqslant 2.
\end{align}
This implies that
$$\nu(0) = (1-p_1)\nu(0)+ \sum_{i=2}^\infty(1-p_i)\prod_{j=2}^i p_i\nu(0) $$
and hence
\begin{align}\nu(0) &= \nu(1) = \left[p_1 - \sum_{i=2}^\infty(1-p_i)\prod_{j=2}^i p_i \right]^{-1}. \\
\nu(n)&= \prod_{k=2}^n p_k\left[p_1 - \sum_{i=2}^\infty(1-p_i)\prod_{j=2}^i p_i \right]^{-1},\ n\geqslant2.
\end{align}
An irreducible Markov chain is positive recurrent if and only if it has a summable invariant measure, so if 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\prod_{k=2}^n p_k<\infty, $$
then $\pi$ is a stationary distribution for $P$, where
$$\pi(i) = \nu(i)\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\nu(i) \right)^{-1}. $$
If not, then $P$ is null recurrent.

Comment: I really don't understand this. How does this use the sum 1 + $p_1$ + $p_1p_2$ + $p_1p_2p_3$ + ... as a requirement for the states being null recurrent?

Comment: $$\sum_{n=2}\prod_{k=2}^n p_k = p_2 + p_2p_3 + p_2p_3p_4 + \cdots.$$ The factor of $p_1$ doesn't affect convergence.